# Ошибка при запуске сервера NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Пытаюсь запустить код для создания сервера и получаю ошибку

```
events.js:292
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Вот код который запускаю

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Помогите решить данную проблему

Comment: а вы уверены что у вас порт 3000 не занят, ничего не запущено, возможно после прошлого запуска забыли закрыть ноду?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten и правда, оказалось занят прошлым  проектом, спасибо большое , из за своей невнимательности уже полчаса думаю в чем может быть ошибка)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten не подскажете как закрыть теперь тот порт?

Comment: просто запершить приложение, если это консоль, то Ctrl+C

Comment: @ExplodingKitten хмммм, уже было удалено это приложение , но порт остался на прослушке

Comment: крешнуть процусс, ребут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send({hello: true});
});

// app.listen(3000); // без callback
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('online - localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. например, можно описать, что именно приводит к ошибке.